# How can i join 2 tables with option values on certain column

Tags: mysql, sql

On table1

```
+-------+-------+
| unid1 | unid2 |
+-------+-------+
|     1 |     1 |
|     2 |     2 |
|     3 |     3 |
+-------+-------+
```

On table 2

```
+---------+-------+-------+------+
| tableid | unid1 | unid2 | type |
+---------+-------+-------+------+
|       1 |     1 |     1 |    1 |
|       2 |     2 |     2 |    1 |
|       3 |     3 |     3 |    1 |
|       4 |     3 |     0 |    2 |
|       5 |     3 |     0 |    2 |
|       6 |     4 |     4 |    3 |
|       7 |     5 |     5 |    3 |
+---------+-------+-------+------+
```

Expected result.

```
+-------+-------+------+
| unid1 | unid2 | type |
+-------+-------+------+
|     1 |     1 |    1 |
|     2 |     2 |    1 |
|     3 |     3 |    1 |
|     3 |     0 |    2 |
|     3 |     0 |    2 |
+-------+-------+------+
```

My SQL code

```
select t1.*, t2.* from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t1.unid1 = t2.unid1 and t1.unid2 = t2.unid2 and 
t2.type in (1 , 2);
```

My SQL query does not give the result that i wanted, how can i get the result that i want.

Comment: You need a simple join, looking at input and output looks like just uniq1 would be the join column in both tables.

Comment: What is the logic to be applied to get the desired output?

Comment: The data set isn't very representative, is it. It's better if some thought goes into these things

Answer (score 1):

Your expected output implies that you want to retain all rows in `table2` whose `unid1` values can be found in `table1`.  If so, then we can just inner join these two tables on the `unid1` column.  This assumes that `unid1` is unique in `table1`.

```
SELECT t2.unid1, t2.unid2, t2.type
FROM table2 t2
INNER JOIN table1 t1
    ON t2.unid1 = t1.unid1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to output values wherein the rows from `Table1` matches on `Table2` in both columns `unid1` and `unid2` and that the `type` must be contained with your desired values.

```
SELECT  b.unid1, b.unid2, b.type
FROM    table1 a
        INNER JOIN table2 b
            ON a.unid1 = b.unid1
WHERE   EXISTS 
        (
            SELECT  1
            FROM    Table1 t1
                    INNER JOIN Table2 t2
                        ON t1.unid1 = t2.unid1 
                            AND t1.unid2 = t2.unid2
            WHERE   t2.type in (1,2)
                    AND a.unid1 = t1.unid1
        )
```

Here's a [DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c4715/1).